# Why does execution continue, even after catching exception?

Tags: php

Why does this method called via ajax continue to execute after catching an exception ?

Here's an example:

```
try{
    $this->save_order(); //for testing purposed, guaranteed to throw exception
    $this->set_order_number();
    $this->set_plan_id();  //WHY DOES THIS STILL EXECUTE?
}catch(Exception $e){ 
    header('Internal Server Error', true, 500)
    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$e->getMessage());
    exit();
 }
```

The `save_order` method:

```
public function save_order()
{
     if(1==1){
       throw new exception('caught exception');
     }
}
```

Jquery if anyone wants to have a look at it:

```
$.ajax({
        'url': '/admin/payment_plan/ajax_finish_order',
        'type': 'POST',
        'dataType': 'JSON',
        'data':{'some_data': some_var},
        'success':function(status){
                  //do stuff
                 },
         'error':function(error){
                 //do stuff
                 }
```

Comment: random down vote without words? Share what you've to say.

Comment: What do you mean by php continues execution after catching exception? What does it do after printing the json encoded array?

Comment: Exactly  that, the method doesn't catch the exception and stop executing as it should, it continues. See comments on code. For example if line 3 throws an exception and line 5 catches it, line 4 should not execute, but it is in this case.

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce that on 3v4l.org, I've seen (probably) some typos in your code which produce syntax errors, can you make sure these are only typos on SO and not your actual code?

Comment: Since this issue cannot be reproduced on https://3v4l.org/uo812, how do you see that said line gets executed? What does it do and how do you validate that said method gets executed?

Comment: can you please post your class

Comment: Syntax errors are typos on SO. The plan id is set and stored in the relevant db table, this is how I know the method is actually executing. The class is rather long. The exception message is returned to the client though! I don't understand!